# STS vFabric Server v2.9 suddenly doesn't deploy project anymore

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, macos, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

My vFabric Server worked since today when suddenly stopped to deploy any application (also a couple that had been working until yesterday).

What I see is that in the console during deployment of the application are fired exceptions like:

```
Aug 10, 2014 8:26:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Not sure that is related but the working folder of the server (base-instance -> work -> Catalina -> localhost) has only an empty folder for the application I'm trying to deploy (so no files, folders or anything else inside, just an empty folder with the name of the application).

Attempts already tried (I'm running STS on Maverick):

- install a brand new STS with a brand new workspace
- the previous + cloning the projects from git, starting with a fresh copy of them
- removed eclipse and all of its files/directories under ~, ~/Library etc and then starting with a brand new install of STS and a fresh copy of my projects
- runned mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DreResolve=false and finally erased ~/.m2 directory and updated maven projects

Comment: did you try to create a new server instance? Curious to see if that works or produces the same error.

Comment: Tried but I get the same problem.

Comment: That sounds indeed strange. Where is your tc server installed? In case you are on Windows, please don't install STS or tc Server into the "Program Files" area, but that is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, after all the cleaning mentioned before at the end of my question, I've found out that disabling "Workspace Resolution" in Properties -> Maven -> Disable Worskpace Resolution Eclipse/STS started allowing me to run my app in the local tc server.

One correction on my error report: tc server working directory is *base-instance -> wtpwebapps* and not *base-instance -> work -> Catalina -> localhost*

But I don't know that happened...